# Is there a way to define a kind of "generic" func to use as a linq order selector

Tags: c#, func

I have a simple object list and I want to apply different filter and order selectors. It's ok for the filter but for the order, I don't know how to define a "generic" selector.

```
// The selector is always a bool
Func<MyNode, bool> isChild = x => x.Age < 18;
Func<MyNode, bool> isAdult = x => x.Age >= 18;

// So it's always ok to use
Func<MyNode, bool> isAgeOk = isAdult;

// The sort field can be different type (int, string, ...)
Func<MyNode, string> sortByName = x => x.Name;
Func<MyNode, int> sortByAge = x => x.Age;
Func<MyNode, int> sortById = x => x.Id;

// --------------> Is there a way to use a kind of generic declaration Func<MyNode, T> ?
Func<MyNode, int> currentSort = sortByAge;
// With this declaration, i can't use : Func<MyNode, int> currentSort = sortByName

List<MyNode> LstNodes = new List<MyNode>();
// ...Stuff to get nodes

// If I have this kind of linq, it's ok, but current sort is Fixed (Func<MyNode, int> in this example)
var result = LstNodes.Where(isAgeOk).Distinct().OrderBy(currentSort).ToList();
```

The simple class definition is

```
public class MyNode
{   
  public int Id  { get; set; }
  public string Name  { get; set; }
  public int Age { get; set; }          
}
```

I know the further declaration fails because of the compiler error CS1662 "Cannot convert anonymous method block to delegate type 'delegate type' because some of the return types in the block are not implicitly convertible to the delegate return type"
but is it possible to define a kind of generic declaration similar to :

```
Func<MyNode, T> currentSort = sortByAge; // <-- Fails Compiler error CS1662
```

or is there a different way to proceed ?

Comment: I'm not certain what you're trying to accomplish but if I understand correctly (apply different filters and orderings etc), I think I would go for just building an `IEnumerble<MyNode>` by chaining `Linq` methods together instead of keeping track of your mutations in variable functions.

Comment: Maybe you want a `Func<MyNode, IComparable>`?

Comment: @HimBromBeere Yes !!! That's **exactly** what I wanted. Many Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As HimBromBeere commented, the best way is using the type IComparable

Code.

```
        Func<PersonTest, IComparable> sortByName = x => x.Name;
        Func<PersonTest, IComparable> sortByAge = x => x.Age;
        Func<PersonTest, IComparable> sortByLastName = x => x.LastName;

        // --------------> Is there a way to use a kind of generic declaration Func<MyNode, T> ?
        Func<PersonTest, IComparable> currentSort = sortByName;
```

Comment: That was **exactly** what I wanted :) Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

All your types implement `IComparable`. As `Func` is contra-variant, you can assign any delegate that returns some instance of that interface.

So this works:

```
Func<MyNode, IComparable> myDelegate = myFunctionReturningString;
Func<MyNode, IComparable> myDelegate = myFunctionReturningInt;
Func<MyNode, IComparable> myDelegate = myFunctionReturningBool;
```

Read about contra-variance here: https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/covariance-contravariance/using-variance-for-func-and-action-generic-delegates

Answer (score -2):

I would just use lambdas

```
var list = new List<MyNode>() {
new MyNode(){Id = 1, Name = "name1", Age = 1},
new MyNode(){Id = 2, Name = "name2", Age = 2},
new MyNode(){Id = 3, Name = "name3", Age = 3},
new MyNode(){Id = 4, Name = "name4", Age = 4},
new MyNode(){Id = 5, Name = "name5", Age = 5},
new MyNode(){Id = 6, Name = "name6", Age = 6},
new MyNode(){Id = 7, Name = "name7", Age = 7},
new MyNode(){Id = 8, Name = "name8", Age = 8},
        };

        var result = list.Where(n => n.Age >= 3).OrderBy(n => n.Age).ToList();
```

[Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/UeGTU4)

Comment: That's not an answer to the question.

Answer (score -2):

You could use `IComparable`.

https://dotnetfiddle.net/23R97J

```
    Func<MyNode, IComparable> sortByName = x => x.Name;
    Func<MyNode, IComparable> sortByAge = x => x.Age;
    Func<MyNode, IComparable> sortById = x => x.Id;
    var currentSort = sortByAge;
```

EDIT: Like other people already mentioned, it's much better to use `IComparable` instead of `object`, what I suggested before.